# Numbering Images in Marginpar

Tags: graphics, marginpar

I would like to add some small images into the marginpar. The purpose of the images is to add some additional 'nice to know' information, but they are not directly related to the document's content, that's why I would like to have them in the marginpar.

Using the code

```
\marginpar{\sffamily\scriptsize \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{img/gauss.jpg} Johann Carl Friedrich Gauß (latinisiert Carolus Fridericus Gauss; * 30. April 1777 in Braunschweig; † 23. Februar 1855 in Göttingen) war ein deutscher Mathematiker, Astronom, Geodät und Physiker. Er galt bereits zu seinen Lebzeiten als Princeps Mathematicorum („Fürst der Mathematiker“).}
```

gives me a nice figure in the marginpar, but I want it to be numbered and also appear in the LOF. I tried to use \captionof which I saw in some samples here, but that command is not known. How can I sort of 'fake' the figure caption, like a real figure caption, and also add the figure to the LOF?

That's what I get:
[image]

And this is what I want:
[image]

This second picture I have faked by manually entering the text for the caption :-)

Comment: You need the `caption` package for `\captionof`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know the caption package. However, I have found another cool way, using the following code:

```
\newsavebox{\@margin@floatbox}
\newenvironment{@margin@float}[2][-1.2ex]%
  {\FloatBarrier\begin{lrbox}{\@margin@floatbox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}%
% can swap left/right align if desired.
%      \checkoddpage
%      \ifoddpage
%        \def\captionstyle{\sffamily\scriptsize\raggedleft}
%      \else
        \def\captionstyle{\sffamily\scriptsize\raggedright}
%      \fi
    \def\@captype{#2}%
    \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
    \noindent%
  }
  {\end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \marginpar{\usebox{\@margin@floatbox}}%
  }

\newenvironment{marginfigure}[1][-1.2ex]%
  {\begin{@margin@float}[#1]{figure}}
  {\end{@margin@float}}
```

This works very well and lets me use labels and all that stuff in the margin. I simply use

```
\begin{marginfigure}
% includegraphics or whatever
\caption[short caption]{here comes the caption}
\label{any label}
\end{marginfigure}
```

But I am unsure whether it is better from a typographic poit of view to use justified or left aligned text.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use automatic numbering and some description, `\caption` can't be used here, since `\marginpar` (nor `\marginnote`) is a floating environment, but `\captionof{figure}` will work. This requires the `caption` box, which is highly recommended due to its high configurability.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[rmargin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\section{A section on Ducks}
\marginnote{%
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente}\captionof{figure}{A nice duck}%
}
\blindtext

\blindtext

\marginnote{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{beeduck}\captionof{figure}{Yet another nice duck}}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]